# Tree View Events Order

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Please help me about the event order of any custom `Treeview` control.
I have to highlight the selected node of `Custom  Treeview`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the most open question I've read...

Have you read the documentation on treeviews: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx ?

You have property such as "SelectedNode", I guess this is what you're looking for?

Edit:
You bind to an item source, then you can specify the selected node afterwards. Maybe this link will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759035(v=vs.95).aspx